# Insert realtime data in Canvas js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been working some days with Canvas JS and made some amazing realtime diagrams, but the problem is; data is only random generated. I have managed to get some data from an sensor, and I wish to insert this data into Canvas JS, and remove random generated data, but I can not figure out how to replace the real data with random generated data?

Just to repeat my question, what modifications do I need to do in order to insert realtime data instead of random generated data?

Here is the code I got from Canvas JS ([Code Example from canvasjs](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title :{
            text: "Live Random Data"
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 20;
    var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }

        chart.render();     

    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://IP(hidden):8081/osc");

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title :{
            text: "Live Random Data"
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 20;
    var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
      var point = evt.data.split(",");

       // To ensure we have recieved both x and y values
      if ( point.length === 2 ){
          dps.push({
             x: parseInt( point[0] ),
             y: parseInt( point[1] )
          });
      }

      if (dps.length > dataLength){
         dps.shift();               
      }

      chart.render();
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Lakha Singh Namdhari, the code below is where I receive my temperature, what I am confused over is how I can combine together the code below with what you have came up with, is it possible to get any tips or examples?

            ws = new WebSocket("ws://IP(hidden):8081/osc");

            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                var point = evt.data.split(",");
                dps.push([point[0], point[1]]);

                if(dps.length > dataLength){
                    dps.shift();
                    //ws.close();
                }
            }

Comment: Thank you, I am getting closer and closer to my goal! When I run the code, I can see the horizontal and vertical line (x,y) + the title "Live Random Data", but there is no data streaming into the diagram? There is something not working correctly in the code above, because I can see the data streaming in from my terminal, but not in the diagram.. Btw the data is between 38-39.

Comment: Can you share a url or fiddle where your latest code is ?

Comment: Thanks . But I meant in running state, so that we can find it out whats missing .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me Mr. Lakha Singh Namdhari! The diagram is now receiving data, the only thing I had to do was to remove the if statement around the code. Because this if statement gave me only 0s for dps.length.. The problem was that **dps.length** was equal to 0 (constant). So when I removed the if statement, the **dps.length** started to increment correctly.

I have some things left such as design and time delay etc, but I will start a new thread because this questions is solved.

I changed this:

```
                  if ( point.length === 2 ){
                      dps.push({
                         x: parseInt( point[0] ),
                         y: parseInt( point[1] )
                      });
                  }
```

To this:

```
              dps.push({
                 x: parseInt( point[0] ),
                 y: parseInt( point[1] )
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have basically created a diagram where it stores temperature values. Everything works great, the only problem is that the x-axis does not go out from the frame. I want the x-axis to move with the data. Like the link below.

[Here is the example!](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)

This is the code, I have hidden the IP for security reasons. What shall I implement in order to make the x-axis move with the data?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {

        var dps = []; // dataPoints

        // Connect to the server. 
        var server_url = "ws://";
        var ip = 'xxx.xxx.x.xx';
        server_url = server_url.concat(ip,":8081/osc")
        ws = new WebSocket(server_url);

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title :{
                text: "Temp Bank Sensor 1 - (TBS1)"
            },          
            data: [{
                type: "splineArea",
                color: "rgba(255, 0, 29, 0.79)",
                dataPoints: dps 
            }]
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100; 
        var updateInterval = 20;
        var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

        ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            var point = evt.data.split(",");

                  dps.push({
                     x: xVal,
                     y: parseInt( point[1] )
                  });
                  xVal++; 

              if (dps.length > dataLength){
                 dps.shift();               
              }
              chart.render();
        } // end method ws.onmessage

            // generates first set of dataPoints
            updateChart(dataLength); 

            // update chart after specified time. 
            setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 


    }; // end method window.onload 

    </script>
```